# Allow a custom response when responding No Thanks on Careers

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, jobs

I just got a hit on careers (Thanks Jeff et al!!), but I wasn't interested. I wanted to decline, but say more than just "No Thanks".

Can you add the ability to add a message that will go along with the No Thanks response? Declining without saying anything else feels way to impersonal.

Answer (score 3):

You can now add a short response to the potential employer in all cases

Comment: Great! I love it! There is, however, a minor bug in this new functionality: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41868/responses-on-careers-are-shortened-cropped

Answer (score 1):

Me too (sorry AOL flashback)
I would like to say - thanks but not moving to New York (particularly as I'm not even in the USA)

On this note there is only a 'would you relocate' option.
There is no way to list which countries you can / would want to - work in.

Comment: That's not true, you can list as many locations as you want where you want to work.

Comment: ok thanks - I hadn't spotted that. So I should list places I can work in order eg. London -> UK -> Eu as new locations ?

Does this tie into the employer search ?

Comment: Yes, list as many locations as you want. Locations be as small or as large of an area as you require; usually smaller is better, but "United Kingdom" and "Europe" are fine, too. When employers search for candidates by location, any intersections will be returned in the results.

Comment: For example, if you entered "London" as a location and an employer searches for candidates willing to work in the "United Kingdom", your CV will be returned. The reverse is true, as well - if your objective is to work in the "United Kingdom," employers searching for candidates willing to work in "London" would return your CV.

Comment: Thanks Jarrod, you might want to give some thought to the rules. I can work anywhere in the Eu. If somebody posted a job in Germany would listing Europe as a location match their search, or I would I have to list every Eu country separately?