# Responses on Careers are shortened/cropped

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, linebreak

In responding to a job offer on careers.stackoverflow.com, I formatted my message in paragraphs. It surprisingly fit exactly in the 500 (?) allowed characters.

However, when reviewing the sent message, it appeared cropped: 8 characters were cropped from the end of my message. Incidentally, I had 8 linebreaks in my message.

Since I am on a Windows machine, I believe the JavaScript counter is not taking the `\r\n` (CRLF) into account: these are two characters as opposed to one.

Aside from that, upon review, my message appears without any line breaks at all.

Comment: way to fit your response!

Comment: One tries one's best!